# Associating Child package calls from Parent package with User defined variables in SSIS 2008 R2

Tags: ssis

This may be a question for which the solution is already out there but I have just not been able to get it. I am using VS 2008, Sql Server 2008 R2. So, here's the scenario.

I have a package called P1.dtsx. This package contains a Script Component as a source. And I have another package P2.dtsx, which already has a lot of components in it.

Now, what I want to do is to call P1 from P2 at two places in P2 using Execute Package Task. I want to set a User Variable in P1 with different values when I call it from two places in P2.

So, I made a variable called T(of String type and scope as P1) in P1 and used it in the Script Component of P1. Now, I have to set this variable twice from P2. So, I went to P2 and made two User Variables T1 and T2(both of String type and scope as P2). Next I went to P1 and opened the Package Configuration wizard and configured the Parent Package variables T1 and T2 to set the variable value T. So far so good.

Here's the tiny bit I am unable to do - I am unable to say that for this call use T1 and for the next call use T2. How do I attach my variables to the different Execute Package tasks. I mean how do I say that when executing package P1 from one place in P2, use T1 and when executing package P1 from the other place in P2, use T2? I am unable to associate the child package calls from parent package with my user variables.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
The image is self-descriptive.

Comment: The same can also be achieved by keeping the Parent package configuration shown as above and in Child package no need to use the Script Task but just make a Package Configuration saying that Parent Variable ActiveT will update the Child Package variable T. Thanks for your response Anoop!